# y_true and y_pred have different number of output (9!=1)

Tags: python, data-science, forecasting, arima

Comparing the actual and prediction with regression metrics such as Mean Absolute Error (MAE), Root Mean Square Error (RMSE), and MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error) for Time series Forecasting using ARIMA model. Given below is the code I tried.
I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (9!=1).
```

Error message image
[image: Error message image]

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import numpy as np

#mean absolute error
mae = mean_absolute_error(test, forecast)

#root mean square error
mse = mean_squared_error(test, forecast)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)

#mean absolute percentage error
mape = (forecast - test).abs().div(test).mean()

print(f"MAE: {mae:.2f}")
print(f"RMSE: {rmse:.2f}")
print(f"MAPE: {mape:.2f}%")
```

Comment: Try to print `test` and `forecast` before the `mae = ...` line to inspect what they are

Comment: How are you getting the forecast? Did you pass any parameter to ARIMA to make prediction for 9 points?